# Audit password change in Windows Server 2012

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

How can I see if a password was changed for a user in my directory?  I don't care to see the password, just an event (perhaps in the event log) to show that it was changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute you are looking for is [pwd-Last-Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Using PowerShell it will give

```
Get-ADUser 'userSamAccountName' -properties PasswordLastSet | Format-List
```

You should run this command in an elevated prompt, in the other case you receive the user information but note the *PasswordLastSet*.